# How to sum of two number of a String in Swift

Tags: string, swift

How can I add two number in a string, I do this here but it doesn't work, it says at the line

`var result = Int(char1) + Int(char2)`

**cannot invoke initializer for type 'int' with an agurment list of type '(Character)'**

```
import UIKit

var str: String = "1 + 2"
var char1 = str[str.startIndex.advancedBy(0)]
var char2 = str[str.startIndex.advancedBy(4)]

var result = Int(char1) + Int(char2)
```

**Edit1:**

After do as @Phillip Mills said, it works, but I have one small question:

```
import UIKit

var str: String = "1 + 2"
var char1 = str[str.startIndex]
var char2 = str[str.endIndex] //error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BADINSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).

var result = Int(String(char1))! + Int(String(char2))!
```

Why str.startIndex work, but str.endIndex not work?

https://www.freewebmentor.com/2018/02/swift-program-add-two-numbers.html

Comment: Why just not separate string by `+` then truncate and sum elements in an array?

Comment: In the Swift Standard Library, `endIndex` is always "A 'past-the-end' element index; the successor of the last valid subscript argument". So you're trying to access an element, which exceeds the last element. The last element is at `endIndex.advancedBy(-1)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you know that the separator will be " + " then you can use

```
let str = "1 + 2"
let sum = str.componentsSeparatedByString(" + ").flatMap{ Int($0) }.reduce(0) { $0 + $1 }
```

This allows you to add more than one digit numbers and add more than two at a time i.e.:

```
let str = "1 + 2 + 432"
```

Comment: Instead of `.map { Int($0) }.filter { $0 != nil }`, you can simply use `.flatmap { Int($0) }`. This removes all `nil` values.

Comment: Thanks. I've edited my answer to take advantage of this

Answer (score 3):

You can create a String from a Character and an Int from a String, so one possibility is:

```
var result = Int(String(char1))! + Int(String(char2))!
```

Comment: I have 1 more question, please check my edit question.

Comment: @khuong291 with my answer you can avoid all this kind of problem, you cannot index the string in the end of the string use this line instead `var char2 = str[str.endIndex.predecessor()]`

Answer (score 3):

Even if your question is only for two numbers, you can benefit from the following code using regular expressions and combining with the function `map` and `reduce` to get all the numbers in the string:

```
func matchesForRegexInText(regex: String!, text: String!) -> [String] {

   do {
       let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex, options: [])
       let nsString = text as NSString
       let results = regex.matchesInString(text,
        options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, nsString.length))
       return results.map { nsString.substringWithRange($0.range)}
   } catch let error as NSError {
       print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
       return []
   }
}


let string = "1 + 2 + 3 + 4"
let sum = matchesForRegexInText("[0-9]", text: string).map { Int($0)! }.reduce(0, combine: +)
print(sum) // 10
```

The above code use the `matchesForRegexInText` to extract all the numbers in the string and then with the `map` function convert all the numbers to `Int` and with the `reduce` function get the cumulative sum.

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 3):

`NSExpression` is a fairish underestimated class in Cocoa which can do that in a pretty smart way.

```
let string = "1 + 2"
let arithmeticExpression = NSExpression(format: string)
let additionResult = arithmeticExpression.expressionValueWithObject(nil, context: nil) as! Int
// -> 3
```